# Bigcommerce API Get All Skus

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to load all Skus from a Bigcommerce store.  I first tried to use the API path `/products/skus/count` to get a count of the number of skus in the store as outlined in the BC documentation at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus However, the `/products/skus/count` endpoint is returning `{"count":0}`.  I know for a fact that I have hundreds of products with a sku.  Ultimately I'd like to get a list or array of just the skus in my store.  Has anyone else been able to use this API or know a way to load all the skus in my store without loading all the product object graphs as that is too slow of a solution as I don't need all the additional information nor do I want to page through all my products since it's limited to 250 items at a time.  All of my other API calls are working great so I'm questioning whether there is an issue with the specific API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to get the "sku" property for all products or the SKU resource associated with a product?

The api call at the url that you've given https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus
will return all the SKU resource/object associated with a product. You can either get skus for all products using the resource "products/skus/count" or a specific product using "products/{productid}/skus/count". Both calls works as documented.